# Two Sum confusing bug

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve a beginner problem on leetcode.

*Given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `target`, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.*

My solution works well on some of the testcases, but fail on this:

*

```
Example:
Input: nums = [3,3], target = 6
Output: [0,1]
```

- 

This is my code:

```
let nums = [3, 3];
let target = 6;
var twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let result = [];
        if (target === nums[i] + nums[i + 1]) {
            result.push(nums.indexOf(nums[i]));
            result.push(nums.indexOf(nums[i + 1]));
            return result;
        }
    }
};

console.log(twoSum(nums, target));
```

Output is `[0,0]` here, instead of `[0,1]`.

Where did the logic fail? I clearly pushed  `nums[i + 1]` to the array as the second value.

Comment: `indexOf` returns the first index where a value is found. Just push `i` and `i + 1` instead.

Comment: `result.push(i + 1)` ? Also your algorithm does not work, it only finds consecutive solutions. Try e.g. [1, 0, 1] with target 2.

Comment: As a sidenote: An efficient algorithm could solve this in O(1/2 * n), in case someone wants to write a solution to this on their own (Answering "challenges" publicly somewhat defeats the purpose of the challenge)

Comment: Let's start saying that nums.indexOf[nums[i]] is equals to i

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I should've look more into the code, now after you guys pointed out, code looks really dumb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is incorrect because the elements need not be adjacent to each other. Instead, you should use a nested loop to add each element of the array with every element after it.

```
var twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for(let j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++){
           if(nums[i] + nums[j] === target) return [i, j];
        }
    }
};
```